# IQueryProvider override

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to hook some business logic onto EntityFramework v4, and the best place I can do this is just before a query is run.

I was hoping I would be able to override the default IQueryProvider, simply adding a method hook into Execute(Expression expr):

```
    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        // Do stuff here.
        return this.BaseProvider.Execute<TResult>(expression);
    }
```

However, I'm having difficulty getting the IQueryable to use my IQueryProvider (the ObjectQuery object has a Provider{} attribute, but it's get; only and returns a pre-defined class instance).
Is there any way to use your own custom IQueryProvider in this manner without writing an entire new query stack (ObjectSet, ObjectContext etc.)?

EDIT

Sorry: I'm not talking about adding any new classes if possible EXCEPT the one that implements IQueryProvider. A wrapper is fine in principal but as I have no intention of implementing IObjectSet or subclassing ObjectQuery<T> the wrapper will only be used on the first pass through CreateQuery:

```
    public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
    {
        return this.BaseProvider.CreateQuery<TElement>(expression);
    }
```

After this point, as I am using the standard ObjectSet inside the wrapper the IQueryProvider will revert to the pre-defined one and my IQueryProvider will not catch any futher calls.

So: Is there a way to implement and use IQueryProvider WITHOUT trying to add a wrapper, which forces me to use a full custom stack of IQueryxxx objects?

Answer (score 2):

Yes just hook into the queryable provider in the CreateQuery and Execute methods

```
public object Execute(Expression expression)
{
 //do stuff here
 return _queryable.Provider.Execute(expression);
}
```

You'll just need to inject the queryable object like so

```
public class MyQueryable<T> : IOrderedQueryable<T>
{
 public MyQueryable(IQueryable<T> toWrap)
  : this(equipment, Expression.Constant(equipment.AsQueryable()))
 {
 }

 public MyQueryable(IQueryable<T> toWrap, Expression expression)
 {
  Wrapped = toWrap;
  Provider = new MyProvider<T>(toWrap);
  Expression = expression;
 }

 public IEnumerator<TModel> GetEnumerator()
 {
  return Wrapped.GetEnumerator();
 }

 IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
 {
  return GetEnumerator();
 }

 public Expression Expression { get; private set; }

 public Type ElementType
 {
  get { return typeof(T); }
 }

 public IQueryProvider Provider { get; private set; }
 internal IQueryable<T> Wrapped { get; set; }
}
```